# python3 get nested dictionary/property from yaml file

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, properties, nested

I try to figure out how to get nested data as dictionary/property from yaml file.

The code below works if I provide the function with only one level.
example :

```
result = parse_yaml_file(config_yaml_file, 'section')
```

but fails if I try something like :

```
result = parse_yaml_file(yaml_file, 'section.sub-section')
```

or

```
result = parse_yaml_file(yaml_file, '[\'section\'][\'sub-section\']')
```

python3 code :

```
def parse_yaml_file(yml_file, section):
    print('section : ' + section)
    data_dict = {}
    try:
        with open(yml_file) as f:
            data_dict = (yaml.load(f))
    except (FileNotFoundError, IOError):
        exit_with_error('Issue finding/opening ' + yml_file)

    if not section:
        return data_dict
    else: 
        return data_dict.get(section)

result = parse_yaml_file(yaml_file, 'section.sub-section.property')
print(json.dumps(result, indent=4))
```

Is it possible to parse only on part/section of the yaml file ?
Or just retrieve one sub-section/property from the parsed result ?

I know I can get it from the dictionary like :

```
data_dict['section']['sub-section']['property']
```

but I want it to be flexible, and not hardcoded since the data to grab is provided as argument to the function.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a library to help search the parsed yaml file e.g. dpath

https://pypi.org/project/dpath/

```py
import yaml
import dpath.util


def parse_yaml(yml_file, section):
    with open(yml_file,'r') as f:
        data_dict = yaml.load(f)
        return  dpath.util.search(data_dict,section)


parse_yaml('file.yml','section/sub-section')
```

Comment: The code grab for the property, and preserve the tree structure.

If prefered to start the tree at the given section, use get rather than search and that's it.

Thanks again.